# Getting ImportError: cannot import name 'dist' while installing flask_dance using pip3

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pip, flask-dance

I want to install flask_dance using pip3 but everytime i am getting this error:
*ImportError: cannot import name 'dist'*

my traceback looks something like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kishori/bookverm/alpha/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/home/kishori/bookverm/alpha/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/home/kishori/bookverm/alpha/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip.locations import (
  File "/home/kishori/bookverm/alpha/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/locations.py", line 9, in <module>
    from distutils import sysconfig
  File "/home/kishori/bookverm/alpha/lib/python3.6/distutils/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from distutils import dist, sysconfig
ImportError: cannot import name 'dist'
```

Comment: I think it may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50201005/python-error-importerror-cannot-import-name-dist

Comment: i am able to install python packages outside my virtualenv but i cant install packages inside my virtualenv.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib in py2exe — ImportError: cannot import name dist (File "distutils\‌\_\_init\_\_.pyc")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236377/matplotlib-in-py2exe-importerror-cannot-import-name-dist-file-distutils-i)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python error - "ImportError: cannot import name 'dist'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50201005/python-error-importerror-cannot-import-name-dist)